# Gmock - how to override library function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googlemock

I was trying to override a simple cmath library function - 'pow'

Below is my code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <cmath>

class powInterface {
public:
    virtual ~powInterface() {}
    virtual double pow(double _Xx, int _Yx) = 0;
};

class LibXMock : public powInterface {
public:
    virtual ~LibXMock() {}
    MOCK_METHOD2(pow, double(double _Xx, int _Yx));
};

int main()
{

    LibXMock LibXMockObj;

    EXPECT_CALL(LibXMockObj, pow(10.00, 3));
    double ans = LibXMockObj.pow(10.00, 3);
    EXPECT_EQ(2, ans);
}
```

The code compiles fine but execution gives below output:

```
c:\gmock>
_test_example.cpp(36): error:       Expected: 2
To be equal to: ans
      Which is: 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I am unsure why returned value is 0 - I wondered if we need to add a self definition of 'pow' method so I injected the below code:

```
double pow(double _Xx, int _Yx)
{
    return LibXMockObj.pow(_Xx , _Yx);
}
```

Now the compiler fails to compile the code stating re-definition of pow method - hence how can I implement my own pow library method and call it?

Answer (score 0):

I did not try to compile, but the idea is to do something like that:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <cmath>

class powInterface {
public:
    virtual ~powInterface() {}
    virtual double pow(double _Xx, int _Yx) = 0;
};

class LibXMock : public powInterface {
public:
    virtual ~LibXMock() {}
    MOCK_METHOD2(pow, double(double _Xx, int _Yx));
    double customPow(double _Xx, int _Yx) {
        return 2;
    }
};

int main()
{

    LibXMock LibXMockObj;

    EXPECT_CALL(LibXMockObj, pow(10.00, 3)).Times(1).WillOnce(::testing::Invoke(LibXMockObj, &LibXMock::customPow));
    double ans = LibXMockObj.pow(10.00, 3);
    EXPECT_EQ(2, ans);
}
```